# Algorithm for computing a sum with multiples of specific values

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I am attempting to compute a known sum or closest value to that sum using the multiples of a subset of numbers. In this approach I want to minimize the multiples or coefficient.

For instance if I have the number `120` and I have a set of `50s` and `20s`, I would get

```
120 = 2*50 + 1*20.
```

The set of numbers can be limited however, so if I only have `1x50` and `6x20s`, I will get

```
120 = 6*20.
```

Furthermore if I have only `5x20s`, since I want to minimize the coefficient, I would have

```
110 = 1*50 + 3*20.
```

Note that in this case, the value is the closest value to the sum. If the sum can be achieved, that takes precedence over having the closest value to the sum with less number of multiples.

Is there a known algorithm to achieve this result?

Comment: Simply deciding whether you are able to achieve the sum with the given numbers and their multiples appears to be precisely the multiset version of subset sum; such a problem is at least as hard as subset sum, and hence is NP-Hard. If your problem were solvable in polynomial time, then you would solve the problem I just mentioned by seeing if the output is equal the sum you wanted to achieve, so your problem seems to be NP-Hard as well.

Comment: If it's a practical situation, you can use integer linear programming to try to solve it (even though I agree it is NP-hard, so this won't work in all cases; it's just a heuristic that might be effective enough in practice if your numbers are small enough).